# How to generate Global Error Handler Plugin in Mule 4

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

Mulesoft redesigned the whole error handling mechanism and components in Mule 4 (some key difference here). In Mule 3, there was a simple way to reuse a flow across multiple applications by putting into a separate mule-application and package that as jar. Jar can be added as a dependency in any mule-application.  An important application of this was having a reusable error response builder flow that possibly analyzes the exception and generates client friendly error response with the proper error code and error message for the REST API client.

But when I am trying this in Mule 4 I couldn't do this. Is there any other way to generate Global error handler plugin in Mule 4?

Comment: In a question you should avoid saying it didn't work or I couldn't do it. Instead you should provide details of what you tried and what the issue you had trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can still share Mule 4 configuration XML files in a .jar, you just need to build the file by following some instructions for it to work well in Mule 4. The instructions are explained at this kb: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-add-a-call-to-an-external-flow-in-Mule-4